# Getting an error when starting the android emulator!

Tags: java, android, emulation, launch

When i try to launch the android emulator from the avd manager this error occurs.

`` emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
emulator: ../../src/xcb_io.c:221: poll_for_event: Assertion `(((long) (event_sequence) - (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed. ``

I had Ubuntu 10.10 32bit, installed Ubuntu 11.04 64bit and copied the eclipse ide and the android sdk. Then i updated the .bashrc file and added the export path.

Developing on a physical devices works perfectly.
Can someone help me if i forgot something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you problem is linked to the size of longs. It sounds like a 32bit/64 bit problem.

You should consider installing a new eclipse and a new android SDK suited for your system.

Regards,
Stéphane

Comment: ok I downloaded the eclipse classic 64bit started it and configured the android sdk. but i still get the same error :/

Comment: ok now i downloaded the sdk and redownloaded all platforms again! now works perfectly :D Thanks